# Comparing a complex structure

Tags: c++, vector, comparison, structure

I've been banging my head on this one for the last 2 hours, looking through SO and google for solution. I tried implementing the operator `==` and nested lambda.

here is the struct (multiple nested structs):

```
struct Deepest{
    int att1;
    int att2;
};  

struct Useless{
    int u1;
    int u2;
};

struct Leveli {
    std::vector<Deepest> deeps;
    Useless extra;
};

struct Top{
    std::vector<Leveli> multilev;
    int cost;
};
```

some int attributes are actually enums, but it shouldn't matter for the problem.
So basically, I have a Top object populated, and once populated, I would like to identify and eliminate any duplicate Leveli, based only on the vector of Deepest (I don't want to compare the Useless extra). Here is the code I'm trying to make work:

```
    auto sub_comp = [](const Deepest& lhs, const Deepest& rhs) {return (lhs.att1== rhs.att1&& lhs.att2== rhs.att2); };
    auto comp = [&](const Leveli& lhs, const Leveli& rhs) {return std::equal(lhs.deeps.begin(), lhs.deeps.end(), rhs.deeps.begin(), sub_comp); };
    std::sort(mytop.multilev.begin(), mytop.multilev.end());
    auto last = std::unique(mytop.multilev.begin(), mytop.multilev.end(), comp);
    mytop.multilev.erase(last, mytop.multilev.end());
```

compiling gives me a bunch of error about overloaded function or missing operator== when replacing the lambda with lhs==rhs

Maybe it is impossible this way, then I would have to loop manually over the vectors of both levels and perform a search or review my data structure

Thanks in advance!

Final Solution:

```
struct Deepest{
    int att1;
    int att2;

    bool operator==(const Deepest& rhs) {
        return att1 == rhs.att1 && att2 == rhs.att2;
    }

    bool operator<(const Deepest& rhs) {
        return att1 < rhs.att1;
    }
};

struct Useless{
    int u1;
    int u2;
};

struct Leveli {
    std::vector<Deepest> deeps;
    Useless extra;    

    bool operator==(const Leveli& rhs) {
        return std::equal(deeps.begin(), deeps.end(), rhs.deeps.begin());       
    }    

    bool operator<(const Leveli& rhs) {
        return deeps.size() < rhs.deeps.size();
    }
};


struct Top{
    std::vector<Leveli> multilev;
};
```

Testing with:

```
std::sort(strategy.rules.begin(), strategy.rules.end());
auto last = std::unique(strategy.rules.begin(), strategy.rules.end());
strategy.rules.erase(last, strategy.rules.end());
```

Warning!!:
The vector deeps (std::vector) should be sorted (std::sort) before pushing back the Leveli object in the multilev vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test all these successfully and it should be enough to make your program work

```
struct Deepest {
    int att1;
    int att2;
};

bool operator==(const Deepest& lhs, const Deepest& rhs) {
    return lhs.att1 == rhs.att1 && lhs.att2 == rhs.att2;
}

struct Useless {
    int u1;
    int u2;
};

struct Leveli {
    std::vector<Deepest> deeps;
    Useless extra;
};

bool operator==(const Leveli& lhs, const Leveli& rhs) {
    return std::equal(lhs.deeps.begin(), lhs.deeps.end(), rhs.deeps.begin());
}

bool operator<(const Leveli& lhs, const Leveli& rhs) {
    // You need to implement operator< for your sort to work.
}
```

Comment: Also in this case I'd prefer using operator overloading over custom predicates. Your classes/structs will work right out of the box!

Comment: Thanks! Got me really close, I was missing the operator< for the sort to work! But I had to put the operator overloading inside the struct (otherwise I would get linker error about redefined operators)

Comment: I have updated my question with my final solution :)